# Error when trying to start google assistant on windows 10

Tags: python, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

Watched some videos/sites on how to use google assistant api on windows 10, everything works fine until I try to fire it up: See below

You can also see the error message below

I ran cmd with administrator privileges

I searched other people having this problem with no luck

I tried my own luck, trying to change stuff to make it work

Of course restarted because I thought it could mean a "process" like that was already running and couldn't run both

```
Creating new device model
Error: Failed to register model: 409
```

Could not create the device model. A model with the same `device_model_id` (WinGAsst) already exists.

Comment: The error 409 suggests it's the [HTTP error 409](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409). Unfortunately, I'm not sure if that really helps.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by simply changing "WinGAsst" in the command to something random (specifically "Moddle"), dont know why that worked, but it did.
its not so good though, doesn't speak with your phone nor it connects to youtube. just the basic basic functionallity, on a cmd window.